echo the variable with a variable in name
In bash,
a="name"
eval b_${a}=1

above works
what I want to do is to call the content of b_name (which is 1) by b_${a}:
echo ${b_${a}}

but above does not work

U could use either indirection: b=b_$a;echo ${!b} or nameref: declare -n b=b_$a;echo $b with nameref, you could use $b simply: declare -n b=b_$a;b=1; echo $b.

Why not use an associative array declare -A b; b[$a]=1 instead?

Also see BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?).
